# Change text next to radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a website which was partly developed by another party. This website is a mobile repair shop where a customer clicks a device and type of repair. After this he selects to bring the device to the store. Below the selection of date and time, the customer needs to choose the store.

Option1 (currently): Zupthen
Option2 (currently): Winterswijk

Option1 needs to be replaced to: Barneveld.
Option2: Needs to be removed.

How can change this in HTML? I was able to find the current HTML by inspect tool.
The link of the website is:
https://phonexpert.logistieke-baan.nl/reparatie-aanmelden/?_brand=apple&_type=ipad&_model=3411

[Screenshot of the form and the choose of location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P30S8.png)

```html
                        </div>
                        <div class="ic-select-store">
                            <h3>Welke winkel wil je bezoeken?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <div class="ic-single-store">
                                    <input type="radio" id="first_store" name="selected_store" value="Zutphen">
                                    <label for="first_store">Zutphen</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ic-single-store">
                                    <input type="radio" id="second_store" name="selected_store" value="Winterswijk">
                                    <label for="second_store">Winterswijk</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p id="error_selected_store"></p>
                        </div>
                        <label for="aggreement" class="ic-checkbox">
                            Ik ga akkoord met de <a class="terms-condition" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#termsCondition">algemene voorwaarden</a>.
                            <input type="checkbox" name="aggreement" id="aggreement">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <button type="button" class="ic-btn-fill ic-form-submit">Aanmelden</button>
                    </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- form confirmation -->
<div class="modal fade" id="dataSubmitServices" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="dataSubmitServicesLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Kan doorgaan met afspraak zonder akkoord te gaan met voorwaarden.</p>
                            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="ic-btn-fill gray" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Decline (Annuleren)</button>
                <button type="button" class="ic-btn-fill green ic-form-submit confirm" id="dataSend">Approve (Akkoord)</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thins I tried myself I
I try to use Google Inspect to find the HTML Tag/Classes.
I place a html widget (elementor) where i can paste it in.

Comment: "*How can change this in HTML?*" - Why don't you ask this to the 3rd party who wrote the code in the first place?

Comment: I tried to cantact them but they are not willing to cooperate because of conflict with my client. I took the website over because of this situation.

Comment: Your right. I will gather the code of this example and display it in my post. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You mentioned elementor widgets, so this appears to be a WordPress site? Then it is probably likely that these options do not come from any hard-coded HTML template to begin with, but are dynamically created based on configuration.

Comment: Its indeed a custom widget called "model repair". One of the final steps is to finalize the repair order.

Comment: why not edit the plugin files itself?

Comment: How to edit the elementor widget?

Comment: the form doesnt seems to be coming from elementor

Answer (score 0):

this will remove the 2nd div, and change the value and text of 1st, after `Bring it yourself` input is ticked, because the form usually appears after input is ticked

```js
var deliveryCheckbox = document.querySelector("input[value='bring-your-own']");

deliveryCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
  var singleStoreDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".ic-single-store");
  for (var i = 0; i < singleStoreDivs.length; i++) {
    if (i === 1) {
      singleStoreDivs[i].remove();
    }
  }
  var firstStoreInput = document.querySelector("#first_store");
  var firstStoreLabel = document.querySelector("label[for='first_store'] font font");
  
  firstStoreInput.value = "Barneveld";
  firstStoreLabel.innerText = "Barneveld";
      
  }
});
```

```html
<label class="ic-radio" for="item-3">
  <input class="check-validate" type="radio" name="delivery" value="bring-your-own" id="item-3">
  <i></i>
  <span>
    <span class="delivery-title">
      <span>
        <strong>
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Bring it yourself</font>
          </font>
        </strong>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</label>
<div class="ic-select-store">
  <h3>Welke winkel wil je bezoeken?</h3>
  <div>
    <div class="ic-single-store">
      <input type="radio" id="first_store" name="selected_store" value="Zutphen">
      <label for="first_store">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Zutphen</font>
        </font>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ic-single-store">
    <style>.ic-select-store{display:none;}</style>
      <input type="radio" id="second_store" name="selected_store" value="Winterswijk">
      <label for="second_store">Winterswijk</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="error_selected_store"></p>
</div>
```